# How to uncheck an acf checkbox with delete_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a wp plugin where people can join/unjoin an event.

**What I've done so far:**

I've made a custom post type 'tickets' with a ACF checkbox that is dynamically populated with post titles of 'Event' posts. On a single Event people can click a button which will create a ticket post with the checked value of the ACF checkbox. If the user already has a ticket, it will update the ticket post. This all works great.

**What I want:**

When the user wants to unjoin the event, the acf value must be unchecked. I've tried several things like `delete_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $eventname );`

**Part of the code:**

Before this part of code I define if the ticketpost must be created or updated. Then the following:

```
/* Get the current field state */     
    $field_checked = get_field($field_key, $mypostid);             

            /* Check if the posttitle already is checked, if so delete_post_meta */
            if(is_array($field_checked) && in_array($eventname, $field_checked)) { 

              delete_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $eventname );

            }  else {
              /* if not already checked, add the title to the array so it will be checked and update_post_meta */
              $field_checked[] = $eventname;      
              update_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $field_checked );
            }  


        update_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'user', $TheUserID);
```

The delete_post_meta is not working, the checked value is not getting unchecked. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your If statement true?

Comment: Yes it is. I checked it with an echo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check delete post meta.

Assign the result to a var:

```
if(is_array($field_checked) && in_array($eventname, $field_checked)) { 

         $result =delete_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $eventname );
         echo '<h1>'.$result.'</h1>';
        }  else {
          /* if not already checked, add the title to the array so it will be checked and update_post_meta */
          $field_checked[] = $eventname;      
          update_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $field_checked );
        }
```

if it is false you need to check $RegisterTicket is a post id, 'mycustomfield' and $eventname, one of these will be incorrect. sometimes the var to be deleted is wrong by case. A alternative way to do this is to pull it from the database so there is no error.

```
$field_checked= get_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', true);
```

or just delete all keys with that field for the post:

```
delete_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed some bits like you said. `get_field($field_key, $mypostid);` is now changed to `get_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', true);`. I've added the $result var. And I've added some var_dumps to check the variables inside the if statement. It gives: $RegisterTicket = `int(1996)` $eventname = `Opening` $result = `bool(false)`. The field_checked gives: `array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "Suited Reality" [1]=> string(7) "Opening" }` Why is the result bool false?

Comment: because you are looking for array, Mysql dosen't store arrays as such, you can serialize (php function) and save that string and unserialize it when taking from database. which value is actually saved into the database? (check post_meta table). The get_post_meta function will only return one value if true is set. But really for this operation there should really only be 1 key of the same per post!

Comment: Alright. _The get_post_meta function will only return one value if true is set_ Actually it's responding an array of the checked value's of my checkbox. I thought delete_post_meta would be able to uncheck the value, just like update_post_meta would check it.

Comment: I've checked my post_meta table. For example post id: 1996 has the meta_key **my_custom_field** with meta_value **a:2:{i:0;s:14:"Suited Reality";i:1;s:7:"Opening";}**

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. While ACF checkboxes stores their values in an array we need to unset the value from this array to get it unchecked.

Here is what I did:

`$field_checked = get_field($field_key, $mypostid);`

Let's say $field_checked = an array of Event 1, Event 2 and Event 5

In this case get_field is an acf function (so it will return Event 1, 2 and 5). We can also use here get_post_meta with corresponding variables. Then the following:

```
    if(is_array($field_checked) && in_array($eventname, $field_checked)) { 
      if(($key = array_search($eventname, $field_checked)) !== false) {
           unset($field_checked[$key]);

      }

    }  else {

      $field_checked[] = $eventname;      

    }  

update_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'my_custom_field', $field_checked );
update_post_meta($RegisterTicket, 'user', $TheUserID);
```

First we check if the value is stored in an array and we check if the value is already in the array (so we check if it's checked). If yes: We want to unset the variable out of the array. unset works only with a key, so we need to search for the key first with array_search. And then we will unset it, which means we delete the value out of the array.

In short: 
If $eventname = 'Event 5'
$field_checked will be an array of Event 1 and Event 2.

update_post_meta will eventually update the post and save the right array of checkboxes.